# Attach Android Studio debugger to desktop JVM application

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, jvm, android-studio

Android Studio has an excellent debugger for Android apps. Is there a way I can attach that same debugger to regular Java applications that run on my local machine? AS is based on IntelliJ, which I assume has a regular JVM debugger. Has it been stripped out of Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, Android Studio is for Android only. Why don't you use regular IntelliJ for debug? You'll feel at home :)

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Could you please make your comment into an answer I can accept and close this question ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Android studio is for Android only. If you want to debug Java application you'll have to use the original IntelliJ Idea. By the way, you can write/debug Android application from IntelliJ too.